# Invite option in contact list

Tags: android, mobile-application, invite

I am registered with mobile number in an app like registering in whatsapp. Now I want to display invite option in contact list within the app if people in my contact list are not registered.

Currently I am sending all my contacts to match with php database and return status for each contact. But now playstore has rejected my application as it involves uploading user's private data through the API. So, how can I implement it in my app. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Do not send plain-text contacts information to your backend if not necessary.
For your use-case you can use hashed contact info instead of plain-text, allowing your backend to check if that hash belongs to an existing user of your app, but it would be significantly hard to figure out the original info from that hash.

If your registration process works similar to Whatsapp, I assume you use phone-numbers as your user's IDs, in that case, you need to go over all contacts on the device that have a phone number, hash each of them, and send the list of hashes to your backend.
The backend will then check each hash if it is equal to an existing phone-number hash, and return the result to the client to facilitate invites.

Here's an example to create a hash from a string (MD5 in this case), but there are many libraries and options you can choose from:

```
public static String md5(String key) {
        MessageDigest hash = null;
        try {
            hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            return null;
        }

        hash.update(key.getBytes());
        byte[] digest = hash.digest();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int b : digest) {
            builder.append(Integer.toHexString((b >> 4) & 0xf));
            builder.append(Integer.toHexString((b >> 0) & 0xf));
        }
        return builder.toString();
}
```